# Update index without losing data elasticsearch

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I tried to create the new index according to what I need, reindex according to the old, but it didn't work as expected and the data was not copied together

below the old index:

```
mappings: { 
  properties: {
    donor: {
      type: "nested",
      properties: {
        id: { type: "integer" },
        dateOfBirth: { type: "date" },
        profile: {
          type: "nested",
          properties: { 
            ...
          },
        },
      },
    }, 
  }
}
```

below the desired index:

```
mappings: { 
  properties: {
    id: { type: "integer" },
    dateOfBirth: { type: "date" },
    profile: {
      type: "nested",
      properties: { 
        ...
      },
    },
  }, 
}
```

Comment: You also probably need to show us the reindex command you've ran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the object structure you'll need to create a migration program that retrieves all the documents in the old "document structure"/object, change the "document structure"/object and insert them in the new index.